# Javascript IE innerHTML of <select>

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, forms, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the innerHTML of a  element based on the value of the previous  element.

I have the javascript correctly grabbing the current value and everything works correctly in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.  IE is a pain.

sample code:

```
<form action="soap.php" method="post">
    <select name="circuitproduct" id="circuitproduct" onchange="bandwidthfunction();">
        <option>Dedicated Voice</option>
        <option>Frame Relay</option>
        <option>ATM</option>
        <option>Dedicated Internet</option>
        <option>IP Solutions Private Port</option>
        <option>IP Solutions Enhanced Port</option>
        <option>Private Line – Domestic</option>
        <option>Int’l Private Line</option>
        <option>Qwest Metro Private Line (QMPL)</option>
        <option>Qwest Metro Ethernet Private Line (QMEPL)</option>
    </select><br />
    <select name="term" id="term">
        <option value="1-Year">1-Year</option>
        <option value="2-Year">2-Year</option>
        <option value="3-Year">3-Year</option>
    </select>
    <select id="bandwidth">
    </select>
    <select id="sublooptype">
    </select>
</form>
```

sample javascript:

```
function bandwidthfunction() {
var product = document.getElementById('circuitproduct').value;
    if (product == 'Dedicated Voice') {
        document.getElementById('bandwidth').innerHTML = ('<option value="DS-1">DS-1</option><option value="DS-3">DS-3</option><option value="OC-3">OC-3</option><option value="OC-12">OC-12</option>');
        document.getElementById('sublooptype').innerHTML = ('<option value="Special Access">Special Access</option><option>CO MtPt - Special Access</option><option>CPA Special Access</option>');
    }
    else if (product == 'Frame Relay') {
        document.getElementById('bandwidth').innerHTML = ('<option value="DS-1">DS-1</option><option value="DS-3">DS-3</option><option value="OC-3">OC-3</option><option value="OC-12">OC-12</option>');
        document.getElementById('sublooptype').innerHTML = ('<option value="Special Access">Special Access</option><option>CO MtPt - Special Access</option><option>CPA Special Access</option>');
}
```

Comment: IE is indeed a pain. How exactly is it hurting you here?

Comment: That closing tag fiasco really screwed your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, first of all you have a closing tag for the `select` that you try to put inside the `select` element, which makes the code invalid.

Then there might be a problem with how the `select` element treats it's content. When the HTML code is parsed, the `select` element doesn't have any child elements, like a regular element does. Instead the options are items in it's `options` collection.

If you want to change the items in the `select` element, change the content of it's `option` collection. I.e. to add items, create `option` objects using the `document.createElement` method and add to the collection. Example:

```
var opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
opt.text = 'Choose me';
opt.value = 42;
document.getElementById('bandwidth').options.add(opt);
```

Comment: This information was very helpful.  I'll let you know how it works out when I'm able to implement it.

Comment: Hmm from what I can tell this works.  The only problem from what I'm reading is that IE also doesn't like the "onchange" event.  However this was the answer I was looking for so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the "select"-Element and the end of setting the innerHTML-Property. This is not  a part of innerHTML. Its the end-tag of the element 'bandwith' itself.

```
document.getElementById('bandwidth').innerHTML = ('<option value="DS-1">DS-1</option><option value="DS-3">DS-3</option><option value="OC-3">OC-3</option><option value="OC-12">OC-12</option>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a handy hack I came across that works in both FF and IE as a workaround to the inability to change innerHTML on select elements.

```
document.getElementById('bandwidth').outerHTML = document.getElementById('bandwidth').outerHTML.replace( document.getElementById('bandwidth').innerHTML + '</select>' , '<option value="DS-1">DS-1</option><option value="DS-3">DS-3</option><option value="OC-3">OC-3</option><option value="OC-12">OC-12</option>' + '</select>' );
```

or as a function for readability:

```
function swapInnerHTML(objID,newHTML) {
  var el=document.getElementById(objID);
  el.outerHTML=el.outerHTML.replace(el.innerHTML+'</select>',newHTML+'</select>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this problem with IE. I came up with a turnkey solution that works with the following things in mind:

- You don't want to use jQuery
- Need it to work in IE < 9
- You want to append ( not replace the existing options ) string options into an existing select element
- The select must be a type of "select-one"
- Must wrap selects in their own parent element

We have many landing pages requesting the same information (age, products, country, state etc... ) but with different select options. The implementation I use appends new select options. This was done to allow a custom default option per lading page.  One page may have the first option as "select item" another may have "choose one" and so forth.

Select format:

```
<div>  <!-- you MUST wrap the select in a tag without any siblings -->
    <select name="age" id="form-age">
        <option value="">Choose Age</option>
    </select>
</div>  <!-- you MUST wrap the select in a tag without any siblings -->
```

Here is the function to APPEND/ADD values:

```
function addOptions(el, options){
    // checks to make sure element exists and is a select
    if(el && el.type === "select-one"){
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + options;
        el.parentNode.innerHTML = el.outerHTML; // needed for IE
    }
}
```

Now to execute the function pass in the select object and string values:

```
addOptions(
    document.getElementById("form-age"), 
    '<option value="1">18-25</option><option value="2">26-35</option><option value="3">36-45</option><option value="4">46-55</option><option value="5">56-65</option><option value="6">66-75</option><option value="7">76-85</option><option value="8">86+</option>'
);
```

This will generate a select with the options passed, even in IE!

```
<div>  <!-- you MUST wrap the select in a tag without any siblings -->
    <select name="age" id="form-age">
        <option value="">Choose Age</option>
        <option value="1">18-25</option><option value="2">26-35</option><option value="3">36-45</option><option value="4">46-55</option><option value="5">56-65</option><option value="6">66-75</option><option value="7">76-85</option><option value="8">86+</option>
    </select>
</div>  <!-- you MUST wrap the select in a tag without any siblings -->
```

If you needed the script to REPLACE the values use the following:

```
function replaceOptions(el, options){
    if(el && el.type === "select-one"){
        el.innerHTML = options;
        el.parentNode.innerHTML = el.outerHTML; // needed for IE
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows this has been a known bug in IE [since at least IE5](http://alexle.net/archives/150).  You could try to use createElement and make options and append to the select object, or use a library like jQuery and append the html to the node (which must take care of the magic necessary to work in IE).

Answer (score 0):

The real cause of the problem is that due to a DOM parsing/updating problem, IE will not insert child `option` elements into a `select` element. Even IE9 still has this problem (later versions not checked).

You have to put the `select` in a `div` or `span` and replace the whole `select`. Below you will find an example that shows that then IE will play ball as well. Because this innerHTML problem generally occurs when dynamically generating selects, I made an AJAX & PHP example.

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chain(ed) select with AJAX and PHP</title>
<style>
    select {
    min-width: 170px;
    }
    option.toSelect {
    background: yellow;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="whatever.php">
        <span>
            <select id="cities" onchange="getOptions(this.value,'airlinesContainer')">
                <option value="">Select a city:</option>
                <option value="boston_airlines">Boston</option>
                <option value="chicago_airlines" class="toSelect">Chicago</option>
                <option value="newyork_airlines">New York</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span id="airlinesContainer">
            <select>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span id="classesContainer">
            <select>
            </select>
        </span>
    </form>
    <script>
        function getOptions(qValue,containerId) {
            var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ((qValue == "") || (containerId == "")) {
                alert('Invalid selection.');
                return;
            }
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if ((ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) && (ajaxRequest.status == 200)) {
                    document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                }
            }
            ajaxRequest.open("GET","getoptions.php?q="+qValue,true);
            ajaxRequest.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

.

And the php file, which should be named 'getoptions.php' and should be put in the same folder:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$chicago_airlines ='
            <select id="airlines" onchange="getOptions(this.value,\'classesContainer\')">
                <option value="">Select an airline:</option>
                <option value="delta_classes">Delta</option>
                <option value="klm_classes" class="toSelect">KLM</option>
                <option value="united_classes">United Airlines</option>
            </select>';

$klm_classes ='
            <select id="classes">
                <option value="business">World Business Class</option>
                <option value="comfort">Economy Comfort</option>
                <option value="economy">Economy</option>
            </select>';

if ($q == 'chicago_airlines') {
    echo $chicago_airlines;
}
elseif ($q == 'klm_classes') {
    echo $klm_classes;
}
else {
    echo '<select>
              <option>Invalid selection</option>
          </select>';
}
?>
```

.

Be sure to select only the options with a yellow background, in this demo.

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery

`$('#bandwidth').html('<option value="DS-1">DS-1</option><option value="DS-3">DS-3</option><option value="OC-3">OC-3</option><option value="OC-12">OC-12</option>');`